# Reading complex xml files

Tags: spring-batch

I'm trying to read a complex XML file with spring batch, using the [StaxEventItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StaxEventItemReader).
When dealing with a simple structure, it's not an issue. However, I must deal with this kind of XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PivotContrat xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PivotContrat.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Emetteur>
        <Id>String</Id>
        <Nom>String</Nom>
    </Emetteur>
    <Recepteur>
        <Id>String</Id>
        <Nom>String</Nom>
    </Recepteur>
    <Compteurs>text</Compteurs>
    <IndicateurVide>String</IndicateurVide>
    <Policy>
        <Identifiant>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </Identifiant>
        <Evenement>
            <Id>String</Id>
            <Origine>String</Origine>
            <User>String</User>
            <Dates>
                <DateEvt>1967-08-13</DateEvt>
                <DateEffetDebut>1967-08-13</DateEffetDebut>
                <DateEffetFin>1967-08-13</DateEffetFin>
            </Dates>
        </Evenement>
        <Statut>
            <Code>String</Code>
            <DateEffet>1967-08-13</DateEffet>
            <StatutPrec>1967-08-13</StatutPrec>
        </Statut>
        <Produit>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </Produit>
        <Distributeur>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </Distributeur>
        <Producteur>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </Producteur>
        <Client>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </Client>
        <DateSouscription>1967-08-13</DateSouscription>
        <Periodicite>0</Periodicite>
        <Montant>3.14159265358979E0</Montant>
        <Duree>0</Duree>
        <ReferencesBancaire>
            <RIB>String</RIB>
        </ReferencesBancaire>
        <GarantiesSouscrites>
            <Id>String</Id>
        </GarantiesSouscrites>
    </Policy>
</PivotContrat>
```

The first nodes are some sort of header.(Emetteur, Recepteur, etc...)

The policy node is a collection, which can be quite huge.

My problem is that I can only define 1 fragmentRootElementName, which in ths case, cannot be the real root, PivotContrat, for volume issues.

I need to read each 1st level node to marshal them in the appropriate objects (with a JAXB marshaller).

Is there any way to use multiples fragmentRootElementName?
Is there any other way to work with this XML structure?
I've not seen how to achieve this kind of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like your best option is to implement your own [custom ItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#customReader). The built in [StaxEventItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StaxEventItemReader) only supports a single fragmentRootElement because it's the most common use case.

Comment: Joshua sorry for comment in a very old answer, I'm facing the same problem and it's really hard to find a solution. All the examples of XML reading are using a very simple XML, do you have any recommendation?
I created a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664115/chunk-oriented-xml-read-getting-information-from-different-elements-with-spring