# Chunk oriented XML read getting information from different elements with Spring Batch

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I trying to read a XML where I have the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xmlns="http://www.hello.com.br/parent.xsd">
    <fileheader>
        <name>name</name>
        <protocol>134567</protocol>
        <datefile>2022-06-17T07:51:47</DtHrArq>
        <dateref>2022-06-17</DtRef>
    </fileheader>
    <file>
        <filetype>
            <one>Hello</one>
            <two>Spring</two>
            <three>Batch</three>
            <four>World</four>
            <parent>
                <five>010</five>
                <children>
                    <id>885447534111124</id>
                    <value>0</value>
                    <repeatChildren>
                        <date>2022-06-07</date>
                        <value>0.00</value>
                        <repeatChildrenTwo>
                            <id>123456789</id>
                            <value1>309.02</value1>
                            <value2>0</value2>
                            <value3>0</value3>
                            <value4>309.02</value4>
                        </repeatChildrenTwo>
                    </repeatChildren>
                    <repeatChildren>
                        <date>2022-06-07</date>
                        <value>0.00</value>
                        <repeatChildrenTwo>
                            <id>123456789</id>
                            <value1>309.02</value1>
                            <value2>0</value2>
                            <value3>0</value3>
                            <value4>309.02</value4>
                        </repeatChildrenTwo>
                    </repeatChildren>
                </children>
                <children>
                    <id>885447534111124</id>
                    <value>0</value>
                    <repeatChildren>
                        <date>2022-06-07</date>
                        <value>0.00</value>
                        <repeatChildrenTwo>
                            <id>123456789</id>
                            <value1>309.02</value1>
                            <value2>0</value2>
                            <value3>0</value3>
                            <value4>309.02</value4>
                        </repeatChildrenTwo>
                    </repeatChildren>
                    <repeatChildren>
                        <date>2022-06-07</date>
                        <value>0.00</value>
                        <repeatChildrenTwo>
                            <id>123456789</id>
                            <value1>309.02</value1>
                            <value2>0</value2>
                            <value3>0</value3>
                            <value4>309.02</value4>
                        </repeatChildrenTwo>
                    </repeatChildren>
                </children>
            </parent>
        </filetype>
    </file>
</doc>
```

The final resource from this file is an object with needs information mainly from the `children` and `repeatChildren` elements, but I also need the info from `filetype` and `parent`.

The `parent` could have thousands of `children` and `children` could have thousands of `repeatChildren`.

Actually I created a reader like this:

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxEventItemReader<Doc> docReader(
            @Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}") String inputFile) {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Doc.class);
        marshaller.setMappedClass(Doc.class);

        return new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<Doc>().name(docName)
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputFile)).addFragmentRootElements("doc").unmarshaller(marshaller)
                .build();
    }
```

In this way I read the XML but it passing to the Processor the whole XML and doesn't respecting the chunk which is obvious due to I'm using the "doc" tag as the root element.

How could I process this kind of file processing getting the information from different elements levels and also using the chunk to avoid read millions of tags in one execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this is by having a first simple tasklet step that reads the single information needed from the `filetype`/`parent` element and put it in the job execution context (for later use if needed). Then, I would use a chunk-oriented step to process the `children` elements one by one.

With this approach, the first step would only read the "header" of the XML file (only the first few lines) to get the meta-data and the second step would stream the content of the file in a chunk-oriented manner without loading the entire file in memory.